# MVC 5 routeconfig error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "Default", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new 
    { 
        controller = "ImageScan", 
        action = "ScanImage", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }, 
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication3.Controllers" } );
```

I get the error:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/ImageScan/ScanImage.cshtml

Answer (score 2):

You do not request a view directly. You should request a controller action which may or may not return the corresponding view.

Try

```
yourAppBaseAddress/ImageScan/ScanImage
```

Assuming you do not have any other custom routing definied to override the default routing conventions, This will hit the `ScanImage` action method inside the `ImageScanController`. If this action method is returning this view, you should be able to see the result of this views' code executed.

```
public ActionResult ScanImage
{
   return View();
}
```

When the line `return View` gets executed, the MVC framework will look for a view called ScanImage.cshtml in `~/Views/ImageScan` and `~/Views/Shared` directories.

Comment: http://localhost:64950/ImageScan/ScanImage

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /ImageScan/ScanImage
the routeconfig is automatically directing to previous url..How to use proper route config

Comment: Inside my Layout.cshtml I am using
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "ImageScan", "ScanImage", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

Comment: Remove the `area` bit.