# add view in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-5

When I add a view in ASP.NET MVC5 (visual studio 2015) and load it in browser it says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
> dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
> that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: /Gigs/Create Version
> Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
> Version:4.7.2103.2

Comment: Views have nothing to do with a `404` error. It means you do not have a public method named `Create()` in `GigsController`

Comment: You do not request a view directly. You should request a controller action which may or may not return the corresponding view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930541/mvc-5-routeconfig-error/44930655#44930655

Comment: I assume you have properly set up routes to follow the default format as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is method name in the controller and check corresponding view is created or not.